# Java Prepared statement Sql query error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following statement in a java program.My problem is the first question mark(parameter) in the statement is failing and the error message reads :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''hello' ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE + 
>   INTERVAL 1 - WEEKD' at line 1.

Is there something im missing can i not carry out a statement in this fashion ?
The query worked before i tried to add the first parameter and just added a name manually into the query ,Any help will of course be appreciated.

```
PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
   ps1 = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE EVENT ? ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL ? - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY, ? ) "
                    + " DO UPDATE tablename SET status = ? WHERE name= ? AND address= ?");
```

Comment: Try to remove the parentheses from the question marks.

Comment: I tried that also ,i have updated the query to show the new statement

Comment: the issue seems to be with ''hello' i have only added "hello" with no single quotation.Is there a reason this is added to my query ?

Comment: @Maria88 I am sorry if it offended you, but would really like to help you. Did you get your answer for the gauges or still you need assistance?

Comment: I didn't get help no ,It is not an easy thing to get help with or even find out about jquery gauges doesnt give me the layout i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the name hello get quoted since is passed as a parameter, in this case you could remove the parameter and just concatenate the string or just embed into the string :

```
connection.prepareStatement("CREATE EVENT hello ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL ? - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY, ? ) "
                    + " DO UPDATE tablename SET status = ? WHERE name= ? AND address= ?");
```

or going with String format :

```
connection.prepareStatement(String.format("CREATE EVENT %s ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL ? - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY, ? ) "
                    + " DO UPDATE tablename SET status = ? WHERE name= ? AND address= ?", hello));
```

Comment: I would need this parameter to be dynamic if possible ,do you know a way of doing this instead of having a static name ?

Comment: it works ,can someone explain why i am unable to do this in a PreparedStatement setString ? ,I have alot of similar statements to write and it would be useful if there was a way around this

Comment: Because as I've already said when the argument is passed is automatically quoted, and if you quote a table name in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE EVENT your database gives you back a syntax error ...